# IIS Behaving Differently

Tags: iis-7, internet-explorer-9

I have a small website that i published and then i created a virtual directory to host the same.

Now in IE9 when i try to access my site using this "http://localhost/mysite/login.aspx" address, it works perfectly.

But when i try to access my site using this "http://102.12.103.12/mysite/login.aspx" address, it does not behave perfectly. Then there are issues with the CSS.

Although accessing my site using both the addresses in Chrome/Firefox (latest versions) works perfectly.

Can someone explain me the anomalous behavior of IE9.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your src path in css  tag. And please refer below links for same.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/27/http-406-not-acceptable-php-ie9-standards-mode-accepts-only-text_2f00_css-for-stylesheets.aspx